# Increased memory allocation when calling CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have a collection view with the layout set to horizontal scrolling.  Each header section contains a label which needs to be rotated 90 degrees

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
    {
        Collection *collection=self.collectionArray[indexPath.section];

        UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        headerView.tag=indexPath.section;
        headerView.backgroundColor=[Settings getInstance].textColor;
        UIImageView* expandView=(UIImageView*)[headerView viewWithTag:kExpandImage];
        expandView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"expand_%@.png",[Settings getInstance].appBrand]];


        UILabel* label=(UILabel*)[headerView viewWithTag:kCollectionLabel];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",collection.name];
        label.backgroundColor=[Settings getInstance].textColor;
        label.textColor=[Settings getInstance].backColor;
        label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:50];
        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);


        CGRect frame=label.frame;
        frame.size.height=headerView.layer.frame.size.height;
        frame.origin.y=headerView.layer.frame.origin.y;
        label.frame=frame;


        //add tap gesture to detect touch
        HeaderTapRecognizer *singleTapRecogniser = [[HeaderTapRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:)];
        singleTapRecogniser.sectionIndexPath=indexPath;
        singleTapRecogniser.delegate=self;
        singleTapRecogniser.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        singleTapRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [headerView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecogniser];

        reusableview= headerView;

    }

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        UICollectionReusableView *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

When I run this through Instruments, I'm getting an increased memory allocation under GSEventRunModal.  The problem is resolved by taking out this line of code

`label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);`

All examples I've seen all use this method to rotate a label so unsure where I'm going wrong.

Any ideas are most welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try would be applying the transformation BEFORE you add the text, background color, text color and font. That way you are only rotating an empty label, then subsequently filling it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't resolve the problem.  I'm not that knowledgeable on memory allocation but does CGAffineTransformMakeRotation make a copy of the label? which for some reason in my code isn't being released?